# Change price with jquery through <option rel="">

Tags: html, jquery, math, html-select

after having done some research, I seek you for some jquery math help.

I would like to change a textfield, which states the price of a product, through "option rel="

I put the html code here: http://jsfiddle.net/YjLM7/

So if the select list states:

```
<option selected="selected" rel="price-" value="0">50 x 50 cm</option>
```

The standard price is shown.

if I change the select list to:

```
<option rel="price-100" value="1">100 x 100 cm</option>
```

The price should increase by 100 (and go back -100, if first option is selected).

Would apreciate your help!

Here the full code:

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" rel="price-" value="0">50 x 50 cm</option>

<option rel="price-100" value="1">100 x 100 cm, Price add: €  100,00</option>
</select>

<p>Price</p>
<p><strong>200 €</strong></p>

<form method="post" action="catalog/category-1/product-1.html">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="productid">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Add to cart" name="addcart">
</form>
```

​

Comment: Have you considered using [data-](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes instead? jQuery makes it very easy to extract and use those.

Comment: will do some quick reading on those – in what way would that simplify  the jquery math Blazemonger? Thx!

Comment: Further, you should use absolute prices in those attributes and compute the difference dynamically. If your select dropdown has more than two options, your current approach won't work.

Comment: Note: `rel` is not an allowed attribute on `option` elements. Please use `data-` attributes, like `data-price="100"`. Won't help with the math, but makes your code and HTML source cleaner - and valid.

Comment: The problem is, that I am coming from within a e-commerce solution that integrates to my cms (modx). I can state one price, but create option field – so I have to find a workaround.

Comment: Ok, will change to data-price! Could you still help me with the math though? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See](http://jsfiddle.net/6TvTc/6/) this jsfiddle.

```
<select>
   <option data-price="" selected="selected" value="0">50 x 50 cm</option>

   <option data-price="100" value="1">100 x 100 cm, Price add: €  100,00</option>
</select>

<p>Price</p>
<p><strong data-price="200">200 €</strong></p>

<form method="post" action="catalog/category-1/product-1.html">
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="productid">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add to cart" name="addcart">
</form>
​
​
```

and JS:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price"));
   if(isNaN(price))
       price = 0;
   var currPrice = parseFloat($("strong").data("price"));
   $("strong").text(currPrice + price + ' €');
})​
```

​

Comment: Thanks FAngel – would that also work if I could not influence the data-price of the first option? (This has to be empty)

Moreover – how to I target that price-textfield?

Comment: Could you update the fiddle again, still the same for me although I cleaned the cache.

Comment: That works great already – only question: The second price should not be "100", but "200+100" (and back to the first option would be "200-100".

Comment: Second question - is there a way to recover the "€" (other than wrapping it in a new paragraph?)

Comment: @JoeBaumgart so what stops you from putting correct data-price value on select option? As you can see there is -100 for second option and 200 + (-100) gives you 200 -100.  $("strong").text(currPrice + price + '€')

Comment: My e-commerce plugin can just output the price of the product to the paragraph. I then can set-up the second option with a price-surcharge.

this is why option 1 would have data-price="" (no extra costs)
and option 2: data-price="100" (which should be the value for the math changing the product price of "200" in the paragraph).

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was, what I was looking for!!!

(What would you suggest for keeping the "€" a css-styled span?)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach: putting the actual price of the item in a `data-` attribute of the `option`, and altering the text displayed by that `option` depending on what is selected. This will lend itself to more flexibility if your dropdown has more than one option.

HTML:

```
<select class="item">
    <option selected="selected" data-price="200">50 x 50 cm</option>
    <option data-price="300">100 x 100 cm</option>
    <option data-price="400">150 x 150 cm</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.item').each(function(i,sel) {
    var $sel = $(sel);
    $sel.find('option').each(function(j,opt) {
        var $opt = $(opt),
            optprice = $opt.data('price'),
            selprice = $sel.find('option:selected').data('price'),
            diff = optprice - selprice,
            diffaddsubtr = (diff > 0) ? "- add" : (diff < 0) ? "- subtract" : "",
            diffamount = Math.abs(diff) || "";
        $opt.find('.diffaddsubtr').text(diffaddsubtr).end()
            .find('.diffamount').text(diffamount);
    });
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/YjLM7/5/

Comment: This is a very neat approach, I have to say! I will have to try, if I can get this done with the e-commerce plugin of my cms. Thanks Blazemonger!

Comment: As I said beneath, unfortunately that would not work for me, since option 1 would have to have data-price="" and option 2: data-price="100" (which should be the value for the math changing the product price of "200" in the paragraph to "300" and back).